# Opening images sorted by modification date/size/type/etc

Tags: nautilus, directory, eog

Suppose I have a folder with pictures. If I sort them by name once I open one with Image Viewer and navigate to the others the order is respected. But if I sort my files by modification date, for example, I can't do that. Basically, the default Image Viewer only lets you navigate images by name.

According to [this thread on the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1576729) this has been an issue since 2007! Is there a good/easy way to fix it? Seems like such a trivial thing to me.

Answer (score 3):

Well I found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1399898) that installing gThumb is an alternative to it. Other suggestions welcome.

Comment: geeqie is a good alternative too.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a plug-in for GNOME Image Viewer (EOG) that allows sorting by modification date. You can download it on Github. Cheers.
https://github.com/cybereality/eog-modified-date-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the image files to add the modification time at the start of the name and then the image viewer will show them in order of modified date.
Try the following command:

```
for name in *;do mv $name "$(stat -c \'%y\' $name) - $name" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this viewer, that can sort by modification date:
https://codeberg.org/klartext/plio

Bulk renaming prepends the modification-time as epoch (subseconds) to the basename of the files very easyily: Press Ctrl-t for sorting by modification-time, then 'r'-key for the renaming.